# Making a toString for a BST

Tags: java, tree

This is for a generic binary search tree created like a map has a right subtree and left subtree. Three classes I have are an abstract super class Tree, and two children, emptyT and notempyT I want to create an in order traversal toString but something is off it works for most tests but I cannot tell what is wrong here. I cannot use null, or any methods from the string class.

The code:

```
public String toString() {

    String str = ""; // create storing variable for the string to return
    str += this.leftTree.toString(); // left

    str += this.key; // k
    str += "->";

    str += this.value;
    str += " ";

    str += this.rightTree.toString(); // right
    return str;
}
```

Testing error: expected:<2->o 4->r [8->t 10->n 12->e] 14->n > but was:<2->o 4->r [6->x 10->n 10->n] 14->n >

Comment: As a note, use `StringBuilder` or put all of your concatenation in a single like (which will also use a `StringBuilder`).

Comment: @chrylis Thank you Is there no other way than using a Strinbuilder?

Comment: @chrylis I cannot use Stringbuilder. I am cannot use any speciality methods.